# Plot a histogram with bins and data from np.histogram function in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, histogram

Although I found other similar questions none of them tackles what I'm trying to do.

### Aim

I want to create a histogram from data that was generated from `np.histogram` function.

**NOTE**: I need to accumulate histogram data and then graph it. That's why I'm not graphing the values at once.

### Toy example code

The function and data generated are:

```
import numpy as np
values = np.asarray([100, 100, 90, 10, 0, 0, 0, 30, -10, -20, -40]) # 11 values

def histogram(values, intervals, limitInf=-50, limitSup=120):
    return np.histogram(values,range(limitInf,limitSup,intervals),normed=False,density=None)

intervals = 10
hist, bins = histogram(values, intervals=intervals)
```

### First attempt

With below code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.bar(bins[0:-1]+intervals/2,hist, width=intervals)
plt.show()
```

I was able to create below graph:

[image]

### Difference

If I create a graph directly from values like this:

```
plt.hist(values,intervals)
plt.show()
```

I get a different output:

[image]

### Question

Is thisa good solution or should I use another attempt? I'm not very confortable about adding the width to the bins and removing the last value. I accept any other graphing package solution.

### EDIT

If I use instead:

```
plt.hist(values,density=None,bins=range(limitInf=-50, limitSup=120,intervals=intervals))
```

I get same results with no difference. I was lacking setting the same limits.

Comment: `rateA` is defined but never used.

Comment: I will remove that code

Comment: The histograms look different because they use different limits. Both approaches are ok. plt.hist could be easier to understand and fine tune.

Comment: @JohanC is it possible to get the same output defining limits for plt.hist?

Comment: @quang hoangs answer shows how to do it. Normally you would use `np.linspace(limitInf,limitSup,intervals)` instead of range. Range uses a step for the intervals. Linspace uses the number of intervals.

Comment: I seems Hoans removed his answer as it was not what I was expecting